# Force HTTPS on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, https, hyperlink

How can I force Facebook to use HTTPS on all the links inside it?

E.g.
When I click to the Profile link at the top, instead of pointing to http://www.facebook.com/profile.php it points to https://www.facebook.com/profile.php

I think this is a job for JavaScript and GreaseMonkey but I'm not sure how I'd do that?

Answer (score 2):

Update 2011-01-27: According to the latest news using Facebook completely protected via HTTPS is now possible without any browser plugin:
http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=486790652130
It can be enabled on the "Account Security" page ([instructions](http://www.facebook.com/help/215897678434749/?q=https&sid=0sI883exfgrcO1jaN)).

There is a Firefox plugin named [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere), developed by the Electronic Frontier Foundation (EFF) which does exactly what you are searching for.

Additionally it allows to encrypt also the traffic to the sites Google Search, Wikipedia, Twitter, bit.ly, GMX, Wordpress.com blogs, The New York Times, The Washington Post, Paypal, EFF, Tor and Ixquick

Comment: Are there any same counterpart for Google Chrome?

Comment: According to EFF there is a similar project for Chrome but it does not work correctly (insecure).

Comment: What would be the name of that Chrome counterpart?

Comment: It is named "KB SSL Enforcer" but it does not work securely (a limitation of Chome) therefore it should not be used!

Comment: Oh, I already tried that extension before, and yes, it doesn't work. Any more alternatives?

Comment: I just updated my answer as there is no longer a need for a browser plugin for Facebook with HTTPS.